# Expression 'classMap in Tabset@1:20' in ng2-bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I  am working on an Angular app in which I'm trying to use `ng2-bootstrap`.

Here is my `demoComponent.ts` for simple tab control

```ts
import { Component, View, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
import { TAB_COMPONENTS } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

// webpack html imports
@View({
    templateUrl: '/scripts/src/components/demo/demo.html',
    directives:[TAB_COMPONENTS, CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Component({
  selector: 'tabs-demo',
})
export class DemoComponent {
  
}
```

Here is my `demo.html`

```ts
<div >
  <tabset>
    <tab heading="Static 1">Static 1</tab>
    <tab heading="Static 2">Static 2</tab>
    <tab heading="Static 3">Static 3</tab>
    <tab heading="Static 4">Static 4</tab>
    <tab heading="Static 5">Static 5</tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
```

Here is my `index.html`

```ts
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular2/bundles/upgrade.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular2/bundles/upgrade.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="/css/main.css"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <style>
        * {
            border-radius: 0px !important;
        }
        
        body {
            background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.55) !important;
            border-radius: 0px !important;
            padding-top: 70px;
        }
        
        .dashboarContainer .panel-footer {
            padding: 1px 15px !important;
        }
        
        .dashboarContainer a {
            color: #333 !important;
        }
        
        .dashboarContainer a:hover {
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }
        
        .dashboarContainer .panel-body {
            height: 80px;
        }
        
        .tag {
            background-color: #EFEEEE;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        
        .myHr {
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <base href="/">
</head>

<body>

    <app>Loading......</app>

    <script>
        System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        packages: {        
            app: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
           'ng2-bootstrap': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        },
        paths: {
            'angular2/upgrade': '../node_modules/angular2/upgrade'
          },
        map: {
            'ng2-bootstrap': '/ng2-bootstrap'
        }   
      });
       System.import('/rxjs/operator/map');
        System.import('scripts/src/bootstrap');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I run my app it gives me this error:

> EXCEPTION: Expression 'classMap in Tabset@1:20' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '[object Object]'. Current value: '[object Object]' in [classMap in Tabset@1:20]

[image]

How can I run it properly?

Comment: The code in your question doesn't seem to contain the code that causes the error.

Comment: then why i'm getting errors

Comment: Might be an issue in the tab components you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by an additional change-detection turn in development mode.
When the 2nd turn recognizes value changes this means that change detection itself caused the value change or that a getter or function returns a different value each time it is called. This should help you find bugs.

Usually this is caused by a function or getter that returns a new instance every time it is called. Even when for example an array contains the same values but a **new** Array containing the same values is returned this is recognized as change. Try to avoid that.

You can (and should for production) turn of development mode off by calling `enableProdMode()` (as the console output says) before the call to `bootstrap()`.

Comment: How to run app in production mode

Comment: See the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: but it giving me  error enableProdMode is not defined

Comment: Did you import it? `import { enableProdMode } from 'angular2/core';
enableProdMode();`